# Angular ngx-mask how to display preloaded value in the date format

Tags: angular, date, ngx-mask

WE are using ngx-mask version 16 in our project. when we give mask="d0/M0/0000" it was displaying in date format but in wrong pattern..
We are trying to display prepopulated value to one date field  the preloaded date field value is  this "2021-03-03T00:00:00" but it was displayed in Ui as like this "20/21/0303"
but i wanted to display in this format "03/03/2021" can someone help me achieve that.